# Why is the following (attached screenshot) file size shown negative bytes?

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, filemanager, file-format

[image]

OS used : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS DE: GNOME 
App screenshot : Virtual Machine Manager 
What is the meaning of -1 byte? is it possible in the world of computer science to have such a file size?
Please explain, Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files can not be less than 0 bytes. Files are written on a storage device (like a harddisk), and there is a table of contents (TOC) at the start of that storage device. This TOC lists all the files on the disk, and where they begin.

If a file were to have a size of -1, it would overwrite the space occupied by the file before it. (This is simplified though. In reality, there sometimes exist space between two files, when for example a file in between was deleted. And you would also have to take blocksize into account. But the problem of overwriting is still there.)

I do not know what Virtual Machine Manager means by a file size of -1, does the documentation say anything?

Comment: I didn't check the documentation as the VM worked as expected and did it's job. Thank you for in depth explanation.